# How can I Expand a Parent CSS Accordion, When Child Accordion Border Overlaps Parent Border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

## Resources and Context

https://jsfiddle.net/wwx100f8/69/

I am trying to create an expandable/collapsable accordion to hold restaurant food options, a digital menu similar to Just-Eat or Hungry House.

Using W3Schools, I have tried to implement the Animated Accordion to make this digital food menu.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

## The Problem

As you can see in my code, I have attempted to 'nest' the `<button class="accordion">` within another.

However, the nested accordion once expended, does not then expand it's parent container.
This results in the child accordion's content being hidden or cut off.

This issue is resolved by collapsing the parent accordion, after the child accordion has been opened. But this is inconvenient for the user.

## What I Think I Need

I think I need some way to set the css so that the accordion containers fit around the child content. They appear to be fixed until clicked on.

I'm also open to any suggestions about how else I may achieve this 'digital menu'.

## My Example Code

https://jsfiddle.net/wwx100f8/69/

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>The Text in Section 1</p>
      <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>The Text in Section 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of setting an absolute value for `max-height` of your `div.panel`, try setting `max-height` to `initial`, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/wwx100f8/81/).

however, doing that breaks your animation, you can either switch to using jquery for animation (`.slideUp`/`.slideDown` or [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)) which doesn't have this issue, or try some trickery with timers: https://jsfiddle.net/wwx100f8/80/

Comment: That's great Bor691, works just like how I described. The unexpected problem is that the child categories are a little smaller than the parent. Meaning the deeper I go, the smaller the category button. Is there any way around this? Thanks again.

Comment: @phpN00b they are smaller because of the padding you gave to the `.panel` in line 31 of css in jsfiddle, removing that makes them all the same size.